# Getting list information into a dropdownlist

Tags: web-part

I have a list containing fields "FirstName" and "Status". The "Status" field is a dropdown list containing "New" and "Published" options. I intend to code a visual webpart that will display the FirstName when the Status is set to New.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(@"http://sharesrv"))
            {
                using (SPWeb website = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList mainList = website.Lists["Main List"];
                    SPQuery ourQuery = new SPQuery();
                    ourQuery.Query = @"<Query>
                                        <Where>
                                            <Or>
                                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>New</Value></Eq>
                                                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Published</Value></Eq>
                                            </Or>
                                        </Where>
                                        <OrderBy>
                                            <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' />
                                        </OrderBy>
                                       </Query>";
                    SPListItemCollection itemCollection = mainList.GetItems(ourQuery);
                    foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
                    {
                        DropDownList1.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

I hope the CAML query is correct, if not please correct me. Now I used the DropDownList control to display the "FirstNames" into it, but I am unable to do and I am getting this error.

cannot convert from 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Please suggest the modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `<Query>` and `</Query>` when building `ourQuery` and change foreach loop to:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Title));
}
```

Everything else looks ok. Try it and report back if you have some more issues.

Comment: Hello Vedran, I tried the tip that you gave me....dList.Items.Add(new ListItem(item["FirstName"].ToString())); But the dropdown list doesn't display anything. It supposed to display the info from "FirstNames" column. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you remove `<Query>` tag form `ourQuery.Query`? Can you verify that `itemCollection` is not empty?

Answer (score -1):

If it is webpart, then inherit the proper webpart class. Instead of extending your class with **WebPart**. You can extend it microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart. It will work for sure .. chk it....